# How kotlin handles value type and reference type?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am shifted from c# to kotlin. Not sure how kotlin handles reference type and value type data types, also not sure how kotlin handles the reference when we assign one variable to another like following

```
var x = 14
var y = x
y = 5
println(x)
```

I am not sure it will print 14 or 5

Thanks

Comment: since you are priniting 'x' value will be 14  and 'y' will be 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, it is irrelevant how Kotlin would treat values vs. references because you are reassigning the variable, not modifying it through a member function or property.

If we modify the example so your number is wrapped in a mutable object like this:

```
class WrappedInteger(var value: Int)

var x = WrappedInteger(14)
var y = x
y.value = 5
println(x.value) // prints "5"
```

The value of `x` is modified to 5 when you call the setter for `y.value` because `y` is pointing to the same object as `x`.

I think C# is the same way, but you can sum up the behavior like this: Kotlin always passes by value, and *references* are immutable pointers that are implicitly dereferenced when you access their members. So references are also passed by value...you just can't see or modify the value (the address of what it's pointing to).

Kotlin does not have `structs` like C#, so you can't pass a group of data by value (copying it). It does have `data` classes, which come with a pre-generated `copy()` function that you can call manually. You can also define all the properties of your data class as read-only `val`, so you don't have to worry about the passed object being modified by some function.